# Trying to replicate form post data in requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I can make this work with Advanced Rest Client, but not with python requests. This is how it's supposed to look:

```
POST https://somedomain.com/dev/WebAPI/api/comment HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Token YOUR_TOKEN
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPnWcjZhRHdKiAWdv

------WebKitFormBoundaryPnWcjZhRHdKiAWdv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rootMessageId"
14697
------WebKitFormBoundaryPnWcjZhRHdKiAWdv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mypicture.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
<image data>
------WebKitFormBoundaryPnWcjZhRHdKiAWdv--
```

My requests looks like this:

```
headers = {"Authorization": "Token mysecrettoken", "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
files = {'file': open("861311006159023.jpg", "rb")}
payload = {"rootMessageId":284737}

r = requests.post("https://somedomain.com/za/WebAPI/api/comment", headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
print(r.json())
```

This return

> The rootMessageId property is required and cannot be NULL or 0.

I'm using application/x-www-form-urlencoded only because the Advanced Rest Client does that and it works. When I remove the content-type from requests header it seems like the image data is not correct.

When I change content type to mulitiform/form-data it then throws this error:

```
>     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
>     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
> 0)
```

Comment: Try `header` **without** `Content-Type`.

Comment: Try `multiform` instead of `mulitiform`.